# Need help with identification of bonsai tree

Tags: identification, bonsai

I just bought this bonsai and I can’t find anywhere what type it is.

Can someone help me please?

[image: image of the bonsai in question]
[image: leaf detail of the bonsai in question]

Comment: Ask the store that sold it to you.

Comment: Hey @Jess and welcome. Someone will identify your bonsai soon, I'm sure. Great and clear pics, this should be a quick ID for one of our experts,

Answer (score 7):

If it’s a bonsai from some hardware store or something, I guess…

… it’s a **Fukien tea** bonsai, a relatively common plant species used in bonsai.

There’s various scientific synonyms for it, some of them are:

- [*Carmona retusa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmona_retusa)
- *Carmona microphylla*
- *Ehretia microphylla*

It’s quite characteristic with its leaves’ glossy, spotted look:

[image: File:Starr 080117-1889 Carmona retusa.jpg from Commons (CC-BY-3.0/Forest & Kim Starr)]

Note that due to its widespread distribution as a “DIY store bonsai” (thus lacking scientific accuracy), an unclear number of cultivars exist (i.e. same species with variance in appearance).

Also, see [this slideshow video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSbTexwZ6QI) or web pics (like [this](http://i277.photobucket.com/albums/kk69/peoplelovemanga/017.jpg), [this](https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/160501d5-4f93-42f3-81e4-d70df91e6804_1.0ca284256c77e2f82a223d4a1523d06a.jpeg) or [this](https://indianabonsai.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/fukien-tea-flower2.jpg)) for reference.

Comment: *If it is*: Shortly after this answer, I had a talk with a neighbor who by chance is a bonsai salesman. He advised against a Fukien, because they require a humid climate that hardly can be sustained by spraying them. I had a Fukien tea once (gift from a hardware store) which didn't survive for too long.

Comment: Thanks dakab for all the information on this bonsai :) I will try to keep it humid as much as I can.